# Residuals in OLS/linear regression with restricted cubic splines

Tags: residuals, nonlinear-regression

I have a dataset where dependent variable (y) seems to be nonlinearly associated to independent (x). Fitting a RCS in OLS seems to be a good option to assess their relationship.

What assumptions restricted cubic splines in OLS or linear regression have to meet? If residuals are not normally distributed, is that a concern? Should I interpret QQplot when assessing the fit of RCSs in linear regression or OLS?

Comment: You seem to be conflating two different circumstances, because "splines go through every data point" only for certain types of splines and only when for every $x$ there is a *unique* response $y.$  Please, then, edit this post to clarify what kind of circumstance you are inquiring about and what kind of spline you have in mind.

Comment: I extended my question, I hope it is clearer now.